# plot marginal means and confidence intervals R

Tags: r, lme4, lsmeans

I am very very new to R and I am doing my best to understand it, but at the moment I find it trivial to use therefore I ask your help.

I fit a model using

```
library("lme4")
model_fit =  lmer(Resp~fixed1 + fixed2 + (1|random1), data=table_data,REML=FALSE)
```

I compute the ls-means (or adjusted means) using

```
library("doBy")
LSmeans(model_fit, effect="fixed2")
```

How can I plot the means (bars with errors) of the grouping variable `fixed2`  and see which groups are statistically different?

Thanks!

Comment: From where come `lmer()` and `lsmean()` functions?

Comment: lmer is from library("lme4") LSmeans from library("doBy")

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? What have you tried already? Why did it not work?

Comment: I want to plot the estimates for the 1st,2nd,3rd,4th quartiles together with the error, plus I would like to know whther the estimates are statistically different

Comment: I do not know where to start...

Comment: If you use the **lsmeans** package, you can use something like `plot(lsmeans(model_fit, "fixed2"), comp = TRUE)`. This displays both CIs for the means and comparison arrows. Don't use confidence intervals themselves to perform comparisons. Use the arrows instead.

Comment: Can two groups be statistically different if the confidence intervals overlaps, but not the arrows? What do the arrows represent and how should I report my results? Thanks!